# Populating GridView from Database C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, gridview

Error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare a scalar variable "@meetingID".
```

I've tried populating the gridview without parameters and it works perfectly, however when I try populating it using the meetingID parameter I encounter the above.

Here is my current code:

```
    private void loadRequests()
    {
        int no = 5;

        try
        {

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(data.str))
            {
                con.Open();

                string meetingSql = "SELECT * FROM Meeting WHERE meetingID = @meetingID";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(meetingSql, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meetingID", no);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(meetingSql, con))
                    {
                        var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        dataMeetRequests.ReadOnly = true;
                        dataMeetRequests.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];                              
                    }
                }

                con.Close();

            }

        }
        catch (SqlException x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Could anyone possibly help as to why I'm encountering this error?

Thanks.

SOLVED.

Comment: try to use   *cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("meetingID", no);*

Comment: Solved myself, was being very stupid. Forgot to change to:                       using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))